# Rotating bits in a byte in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

I am trying to implement right_encode found in the SHA 3 specifications. https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-185.pdf
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq5LA.png)
The specific part I am asking about is found in this image, it is converting an int into a byte.

I tried to implement it as
byte b = (byte) n;
but when I use 1 as n it outputs
0000 0001
which is fine but I am wondering how I would rotate the bits in the byte so that it would end up as
1000 0000
since in the NIST document they have the left bit as the low order bit.

Comment: `b = (byte)((b >>> 1)|(b << 7));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the very specific context of SHA-3 as described by this document:

> In this document, bits are indicated in the Courier New font. Bytes are typically written as two-
> digit hexadecimal numbers from the ASCII characters 0 through 9 and A through F, preceded by
> the prefix “0x”. **In binary representation, bytes are written with the low-order bit first**, while in
> hexadecimal representation, bytes are written with the high-order digit first. E.g., 0x01 =
> 10000000 and 0x80 = 00000001. These bit-ordering conventions follow the conventions
> established in Sec. B.1 of FIPS 202.

This bit order, which is somewhat unusual (but apparently standardized), has nothing to do with how you represent values in your program, it's only how they are written down in the document. You don't have to (and shouldn't, since it would be an unnecessary complication and such likely to introduce more bugs) store bits "in reverse" in numeric variables (eg bytes, integers, etc). You may want to *print* bytes in binary with the least significant bit on the left for debugging purposes, to make it easier to compare your values with the ones shown in that document.

Normally this type of reordering, when applied to the bits of a byte, would be referred to as reversing the bits, while the term rotating is normally reserved for circular shifts. Printing a byte (or other type of integer) with the least significant bit on the left is not really a reversal, since bits do not have an inherent order in that sense.